# How to create table dynamically from user input?

Tags: python, string, sqlite, string-formatting

I am creating a wishlist app using Tkinter and sqlite3. I want the user to be able to create tables in database by imputing names. For that I connected a button to this function:

```
def create_table(table_name):
    connection = sql.connect(f'{directory}\main.sqlite')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE ? (name TEXT, price REAL, url TEXT)",(table_name,))
    connection.close()
```

This doesn't work and I get:

> cursor.execute("create table ? (name text, price real, url text)",(table_name,))
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Is it possible to do string formatting in `CREATE TABLE`? I'd rather create separate tables than one with additional column for id of items. I don't want to use `f-string` as it can be an issue if user inputs commands instead of a name.

Comment: `?` placeholders can't be used for table/column names. You will have to use string interpolation or f-strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this cannot be done. A table name cannot act as a dynamic parameter from SQLite's point of view. You will need to do something like this:

```
f'CREATE TABLE {table_name} (name TEXT, price REAL, url TEXT)'
```

But first you will need to validate the user input for `table_name`. Which shouldn't be a problem if you want to limit the allowed characters to (for example) only 1+ English letters and 0+ underscores. You might also want to validate the table name length and uniqueness somehow.